# Tramp just hangs "Found remote shell prompt on"

Tags: tramp

When I try to connect to my office computer with tramp: C-x f "/ssh:office:" it shows me the message: "Found remote shell prompt on" and then completely hangs. I have to terminate with C-g, if I hit enter the emacs session dies completely. Connecting with "ssh" works fine.

These are the complete error messages:

This is the debug tramp/ssh buffer:

```
atias-HP-ProDesk-600-G1-TWR ~ % 
10:28:01.900922 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
10:28:01.901918 tramp-process-actions (3) # Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
10:28:01.904656 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Found remote shell prompt on `office'
10:28:01.904954 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-shell nil
10:28:01.905100 tramp-open-shell (5) # Opening remote shell `/bin/sh'...
10:28:01.905286 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
10:28:01.905420 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # remote-echo nil
10:28:01.905543 tramp-send-command (6) # exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 
10:28:01.905668 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
10:28:01.905795 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # chunksize nil
10:28:01.905910 tramp-set-connection-property (7) # last-cmd-time (22208 18593 905880 548000)
10:28:01.906046 tramp-send-string (10) # exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 
10:28:01.906184 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
10:28:01.906355 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.906491 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.906637 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:01.906849 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[K
10:28:01.907001 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.907118 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.907240 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:01.909402 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec
10:28:01.909563 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.909685 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.909798 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:01.909939 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/nul
10:28:01.910038 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.910128 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.910214 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:01.910807 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_CO
10:28:01.910964 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.911089 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.911213 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:01.911377 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /b
10:28:01.911480 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.911565 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.911645 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:01.911783 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 
10:28:01.911874 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.911942 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.912022 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:01.912143 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 

10:28:01.912219 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.912287 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.912363 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:01.917431 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 

]0;matias@matias-HP-ProDesk-600-G1-TWR: exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh #$ 
10:28:01.918049 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.918349 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:01.918658 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:02.920243 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 

]0;matias@matias-HP-ProDesk-600-G1-TWR: exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh #$ 
10:28:02.920613 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:02.920815 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:02.921068 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:03.922505 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 

]0;matias@matias-HP-ProDesk-600-G1-TWR: exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh #$ 
10:28:03.922698 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:03.922803 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:03.922941 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:04.923560 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 

]0;matias@matias-HP-ProDesk-600-G1-TWR: exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh #$ 
10:28:04.923871 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:04.924050 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:04.924275 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:05.925124 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 

]0;matias@matias-HP-ProDesk-600-G1-TWR: exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh #$ 
10:28:05.925315 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:05.925409 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:05.925524 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:06.925941 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* run *tramp/ssh matias@office*
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 

]0;matias@matias-HP-ProDesk-600-G1-TWR: exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh #$ 
10:28:06.926110 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:06.926198 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # check-remote-echo nil
10:28:06.926310 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # gateway nil
10:28:07.432947 tramp-open-shell (5) # Opening remote shell `/bin/sh'...failed
10:28:07.434672 tramp-maybe-open-connection (3) # Opening connection for matias@office using ssh...failed
10:28:07.435634 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-truename nil
10:28:07.436239 tramp-flush-directory-property (8) # 
10:28:07.436554 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
10:28:07.436781 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
10:28:07.437118 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # vector [ssh matias office  nil]
10:28:07.437291 tramp-process-sentinel (5) # Sentinel called: `#<process *tramp/ssh matias@office*>' `terminado (killed)
'
10:28:07.437433 tramp-flush-connection-property (7) # *tramp/ssh matias@office* (vector temp-file last-cmd-time)
10:28:07.437559 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-truename nil
10:28:07.437653 tramp-flush-directory-property (8) # 
10:28:07.440201 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
10:28:07.440410 tramp-flush-connection-property (7) # [ssh matias office nil nil] (first-password-request)
10:28:07.440555 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
10:28:07.440735 tramp-file-name-handler (1) # Interrupt received in operation (file-exists-p /ssh:matias@office:)
```

and

```
;; GNU Emacs: 24.5.1 Tramp: 2.2.11-24.5 -*- mode: outline; -*-
10:27:38.949023 tramp-check-proper-method-and-host (10) # 
  backtrace()
  tramp-error([#("ssh" 0 3 (tramp-default t)) nil "ssh" "matias" nil] user-error "Host name must not match method \"%s\"" "ssh")
  apply(tramp-error [#("ssh" 0 3 (tramp-default t)) nil "ssh" "matias" nil] user-error "Host name must not match method \"%s\"" "ssh")
  tramp-check-proper-method-and-host([#("ssh" 0 3 (tramp-default t)) nil "ssh" "matias" nil])
  tramp-maybe-open-connection([#("ssh" 0 3 (tramp-default t)) nil "ssh" "matias" nil])
  tramp-send-command([#("ssh" 0 3 (tramp-default t)) nil "ssh" "matias" nil] "cd ~; pwd")
  tramp-sh-handle-expand-file-name("/ssh:matias" nil)
  apply(tramp-sh-handle-expand-file-name ("/ssh:matias" nil))
  tramp-sh-file-name-handler(expand-file-name "/ssh:matias" nil)
  apply(tramp-sh-file-name-handler expand-file-name ("/ssh:matias" nil))
  byte-code("\300\301\215\207" [suppress (apply foreign operation args)] 2)
  byte-code("K\306\211<\203\237
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the traces, Tramp sends the following command after it has connected the remote host:

```
exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh
```

The output is

```
[Keexec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMP 
[KT
T_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh 

]0;matias@matias-HP-ProDesk-600-G1-TWR: exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=\#\$\  PS2='' PS3='' /bin/sh #$
```

Looks, like there are strange prompt settings. Check the Tramp manual for techniques how to suppress those settings.

Comment: Disabling zsh worked.