# SSH connects, TRAMP doesn't

Tags: tramp, ssh

this is a lot like the issue described [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20300/tramp-just-hangs-found-remote-shell-prompt-on) already.

It seems like the fancy prompt issue, however, I've tried to use sshx which I was told would solve this issue. I an wondering if anyone else have this problem?

Tried:

1. connected via ssh - successful
2. connected with TRAMP in Emacs, hangs at "Found remote shell prompt on"
3. connected with TRAMP using sshx (`/sshx:<user>@<host>#<port>:/`)

Comment: Hard to say what's up. If you want to get support from the Tramp tower, I recommend to write a fault report via `M-x tramp-bug`.

Comment: You need to trace Tramp's execution.  Please say `M-: (setq tramp-verbose 6)`, then check the relevant `*debug tramp` buffer for anything interesting.

Comment: @jch I've done this (under instructions in the IRC channel) for verbose 7. It didn't produce anything extra to look at, just said it failed to connect and then "QUIT" which is where I did C-g to get out since it was just sitting there.

Comment: As a novice, I tried to setup the [`Host` section in  `~/.ssh/config`](https://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) and it helped me resolve my tramp errors, when I didn't have time to investigate.